# ASP.net core, AddSignInManager to get notification when a loggin happens

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, razor-pages

I am trying to get a notification for sign-in.
For this purpose, I created a custom SignInManager and overridden the method used to sign in .
Now if I do the following it works:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
       // ...
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager<MySignMan<IdentityUser>>();
```

But in my code, I use AddIdentity instead of AddDefaultIdentity, and I don't find how to make it work without DefaultIdentity

Answer (score 1):

Can this work for you?

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(option =>
    {
        option.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddSignInManager<MySignManager<IdentityUser>>();
```